# Why does the fire enchant explosion do no damage?

Tags: diablo-ii

I was playing Diablo 2 and got to NM Hephaisto. His fire explosion from fire enchanted nearly did 80% dmg of my life pool. I underestimate that because it doesnt do anything most of the time. Even in hell. Is it bugged? How does it work? How to tell if its gonna do damage or not.

Would appreciate an answer cause I play on Hardcore and don't want to die to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Diablo 2 Wiki :

> Upon death, the fire enchantment will cast Corpse Explosion, causing 75% to 100% of the Unique's max hit points as damage in a radius of 4 yards. This last bonus will be virtually impossible to avoid for those who are close enough to be affected, because the explosion happens barely half a second after the monster's death. Thus, it is essential for melee fighters to maintain a high health level before dealing the finishing blow, or risk dying along with the monster.
>
> In addition, in Nightmare and Hell, minions gain 33% to 50% Fire Damage. In hell, uniques with this bonus also receive immunity to fire.

I researched the thing and found different points of view.

Some players tend to say it is indeed bugged (like in this 2012 [D3 forum topic](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/d3/topic/6037267083)).

Other players tend to say it's working as intended (as written in this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/diablo2/comments/5n2xpo/fire_enchanted_monsters_in_hell/))

I also remember hearing about this "bug" from an AGDQ speedrun of the game.

Unfortunately, I didn't found any official answer from Blizzard.

---

EDIT : Still researching, I've stumbled on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6B82Xu4iBJc&ab_channel=MrLlamaSC) of the aforementionned speedrunner trying to explain the bug.

Comment: Unfortunately they don't answer why it doesn't do any damage (most of the time). According to your Wiki quote it deals 75%-100% damage. Since Corpse Explosion is a spell, there is no way of dodging it if you are in range. Yet most of the time the damage is literally 0. It should at least a little bit of damage. My theory is that it is blockable by shield and/or dodgeable by defense.

Comment: Could your "dodging" come from a character skill / delay (if online) / item protection ?

Comment: You can indeed block it. At least I have heard the block sound from it sometimes.

Comment: @fana Nice video. This is basically what happened to me and why I made this post. Luckily i didn't die. I ll let this question up for a couple of days. I accept u if noone can confirm.